# How to make a layout to behave like AlertDialog in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

The following Screenshot represents my Applications Layout

[image: LAYOUT WITH BUTTTONS]

Is there a way for the complete Layout View (Parent) to disappear completely if I click anywhere on the screen excluding the Buttons by Code.

Comment: create custom Alert dialog with these buttons .......

Comment: do you want to disappear the entire activity or just buttons

Comment: As sushildlh said try using custom alert dialog with this layout. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html.

Comment: @sushildlh how it can be done

Comment: @Ajay entire layout to be disappear when clicked some where else than this layout, similar as in case of alert dialog

Comment: Checkout the custom dialog section of the Android Developers Dialog page https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 1):

To achieve what you have described, you need to use `Dialog` in android.

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context_of_ur_class);
    //if not title required
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    //add your layout in this
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    dialog.show();

    //example for button 1
    Button one = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.one);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do what ever
        }
    });
```

Comment: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application

Comment: final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
        //if not title required
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        //add your layout in this
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_app);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        dialog.show();

Comment: use `your_class_name.this`, not getApplicationContext();

Comment: it is inside a service class not activity class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123042/discussion-between-prashant-gupta-and-sandhu).

Answer (score 0):

First declare a global `private AlertDialog mAlertDialog;`

```
private void buttonsDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder mAlertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        mAlertBuilder.setCancelable(true);//you can change this
        mAlertDialog = mAlertBuilder.create();
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inform_dialog, null);
        mAlertDialog.setView(dialogLayout);

        Button button1 = (Button) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.alert_positive);
        Button button2 = (Button) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.alert_negative);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //do your stuff
            }
        })
        mAlertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    }
```

Call `buttonsDialog()` in `onCreate`. And `mAlertDialog.show` to display the dialog.